# Getting data from a different ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a PickerView which has different office choices and I want to reach this office references as `Strings` in another `ViewController`. My `PickerViewController` class :

```
import UIKit
class PickerViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var officePicker: UIPickerView!

  let offices = ["Choice 1","Choice 2","Choice 3"]
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    officePicker.dataSource=self
    officePicker.delegate=self
  }

  func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }
  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return offices.count
  }

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let value = offices[row]
  }
}
```

I have a home screen which has office informations. I want to add office info which selected before with using PickerView to this screen from a database with comparing the office names.

Comment: @Umair Afzal I tried but had same error as "Value type of NSObject has no member 'storyboard'. "

Comment: so you should be posting that as question

Comment: @Umair Afzal I posted this for your self-aggrandizement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your selected picker in a variable String. First declare it.

```
var selectedOffice: String?
```

In your pickerView delegate, just assign that variable.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
   {
      let value=offices[row]
      selectedOffice = value
   }
}
```

When you're ready to go to next view controller, the simplest way is to pass the data with that viewcontroller. Before that, just create another variable in the viewcontroller that you want.

```
var selectedOffice: String?
```

In your current view controller and when you want to go to next controller, assign the variable as shown below as example.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("frontView") as! FrontViewController
vc.selectedOffice = selectedOffice
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions. I have an error "Value type of NSObject has no member 'storyboard'. " @Syed M

Comment: Thanks you so much ! @Syed M